# node.js writeFileSync is throwing error even when the right arg is being passes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a folder and then inside that create a file (index.html,styles.css,app.js),but it's throwing error that string must be passed as arg but I am already passing a string.

```
<pre>
let fs = require('fs');
let fileName ="";
fileName = process.argv[2] || 'demoProject';
try{
    fs.mkdirSync(fileName);
    fs.writeFileSync((fileName+"/index.html").toString());
    fs.writeFileSync((fileName+"/style.css").toString());
    fs.writeFileSync((fileName+"/app.js").toString());
}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
</pre>
```

the error given by this is :

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2146:5)
at Object. (C:\Users\monojit debnath\Desktop\NodeJsPractice\Practice2.js:6:8)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

`</pre>`

Comment: You forgot to pass any data to write.

Answer (score 1):

The `fs.writeFileSync()` needs 2 parameters.

- `path` - The filepath to write
- `data` - The data to write to the file. (Type `Buffer` OR `string`

You miss the `data` parameter. So it only knows the file, but NOT what content to write.

The result would be something like:

```js
<pre>
const fs = require('fs');
const dirName = process.argv[2] || 'demoProject';
try{
    fs.mkdirSync(dirName);
    fs.writeFileSync(`${dirName}/index.html`, '<!-- boilerplate here -->');
    fs.writeFileSync(`${dirName}/style.css`, '');
    fs.writeFileSync(`${dirName}/app.js`, '');
}catch(e){ console.error(e); }
</pre>
```

[docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)